# confusion in using android:permission for android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-permissions

Please have a look at the following Maniferst.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pack.saltriver" 
    android:versionCode="1" 
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">


   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

        <receiver android:name=".autostart">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name=".hello"></activity>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".service" />
    </application>
 </manifest>
```

Do I really need to use both

```
android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
```

and

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>
```

And what's the differences between them?

Comment: I think there is no need for this permission : android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Change your manifest like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pack.saltriver" 
    android:versionCode="1" 
    android:versionName="1.0">


   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

        <receiver android:name=".autostart">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name=".hello"></activity>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".service" />
    </application>
 </manifest>
```

Here the answer why we have those to.. [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)

Declares a security permission that can be used to limit access to specific components or features of this or other applications.

Therefore, since you are accessing Android's permissions, you want uses-permission instead. The documentation for this element states:

Requests a permission that the application must be granted in order for it to operate correctly.

is normally used when making a custom permission (e.g. when making an app that other apps can tie in to, limiting access is a must), and  is used when your app actually needs a permission it doesn't have normally.

Answer (score 0):

uses permission is only enough, not required to write permission in manifest tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pack.saltriver" 
    android:versionCode="1" 
    android:versionName="1.0">



   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

        <receiver android:name=".autostart">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name=".hello"></activity>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".service" />
    </application>
 </manifest>
```